# Accidentally Uninstalled ubuntu-desktop and Anacron. Reinstalled. What Can I Expect?

Tags: 10.04, apt, cron

Unfortunately when I installed the `fcron` package to take a look at it, I didn't realize that I was also uninstalling Ubuntu Desktop and Anacron.

So, I then did `apt-get install anacron ubuntu-desktop`, which also removed `fcron`.

However, I need to know what instability issues I may now encounter because I have done this change and changed it back. I mean, now that `anacron` is back and `ubuntu-desktop` is back, am I out of the woods? Or, will I lose any important jobs that need to run periodically from anacron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know about `anacron`, however reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` should not give you much problems. As long as the config files for the packages under `ubuntu-desktop` and `anacron` was not removed, everything should proceed normally as before.

And in the future, do try to test things on a different machine or VM. It's safer and you can also learn how to configure it perfectly to suit your needs, should you decide to use it on your main system.

Comment: Otoh, breaking a production system provokes a special kind of stress and adrenaline fueled creativity.. ;p

Comment: We ain't masochists! :<

Comment: The package `ubuntu-desktop` doesn't define/use any configuration files, since it's a [Metapackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ubuntu-desktop), however removing is not a good idea. Reinstalling should be no problem, though.

Comment: Please read carefully I said config files for packages under `ubuntu-desktop`. I'm well aware that it is a metapackage.